# How to get Angular 5 temple name attribute to match Rails 5 attachment attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angular, forms, shrine

I am working on an application the uses a Angular 5 frontend and the Rails 5 backend. Both are APIs that communicate through JSON. Further, for uploading I am using the Shrine gem with Uppy. To get uploading up and running I followed these two tutorials:
https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine-tus-demo,
https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/wiki/Adding-Resumable-Uploads

The problem that I am running into is that to send data to the rails, the uploaded name attribute from the temple and the rails attachment must match for the data to be passed off to the rails application. So, from the tutorials, this:

```
# models/movie.rb

class Movie < Sequel::Model
  include VideoUploader::Attachment.new(:video)
end
```

must match the name attribute from this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="movie[video]" value="<%= @movie.cached_video_data %>" class="upload-hidden">
  <input type="file" name="movie[video]" class="upload-file">
</div>
```

As I am not using a Rails frontend, the data is not so easily passed. Is there some way to reconcile the two. I've tried passing the following to the Rails API as the name attributes value:

```
name="movie[video]"
name="video"
```

I have even tried sending JSON values like:

```
name="{
  "id":"http://endpoint.com/files/226eed1388bbd1b7f029897ad2b86f16",
  "storage":"cache",
  "metadata":{
    "filename":"SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4",
    "size":1057149,
    "mime_type":"video/mp4"
  }
}"
```

As this matches the same JSON format from when I can movie.video in the rails console.

Is there any way to make this work?

EDIT:

Okay, I have asked the wrong question. Sorry, this is my first project that's not following a tutorial. I have spent a lot of time trying to make this work:

```
name="{
  "movie": {
    "video": {
      "id":"http://endpoint.com/files/226eed1388bbd1b7f029897ad2b86f16",
      "storage":"cache",
      "metadata":{
        "filename":"SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4",
        "size":1057149,
        "mime_type":"video/mp4"
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

before I realized that data is being sent via tus-js-client and tus-server. So, the right question should be how to send the correct name attribute to the tus-js-client so it can be sent to the tus-server and finally passed to the Rails application. For more information on the backend, here is the create action and movie params:

```
def create
    movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

                if movie.save
                        render json: movie, status: 201
                else
                        render json: { errors: movie.errors }, status: 422
                end
        end

private

                def movie_params
                #       params.permit(:title, :year, :plot, :video_data)
                       params.require(:movie).permit(video: [metadata: [:title, :year, :plot]])
                #       params.require(:movie).permit!
                end
```

Also, for how I am sending this information, I am using Uppy's in built submission. This forgoes Angular usual submission methods and therefore submitted through tus-js-client(I think). If information means anything, I have spent quite awhile trying every which way trying to submit the name attribute so it matches the attachment attribute.

Comment: You should be able to send this data string in the same way you send any other request parameters in Angular. This data string is just a string value for a specific parameter (it just happens to be valid JSON). For a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request this would be `movie[video]={...}`, while for `Content-Type: application/json` this would be `{"movie":{"video":"{...}"}}`. Your Rails API probably accepts JSON payloads, so it probably makes more sense to use the JSON format.

Comment: I've working on what you said and I think I might have asked the wrong question. I made an edit if you could please take a look. Thank you for the help you have given me thus far.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the role of Uppy (tus-js-client) and tus-ruby-server. Their interaction is completely separate from the form submission to your controller action. First the file is uploaded asynchronously to tus-ruby-server, and for this you can fully rely on Uppy & tus-js-client to correctly communicate with tus-ruby-server. Then you generate the uploaded file data to write to the hidden field (to be submitted by the user), or submit it directly via Angular HTTP client. So, at the point when you get uploaded file data, the Uppy & tus-ruby-server interaction has finished.